# Separate SSL authentication and other traffic

Tags: encryption, tls

For secutiry reasons, I would like to separate SSL handshakes and all other Internet traffic, and send them over two separate networks.

Is there already a way to do this, or do I need to write it myself? If so, any tips on doing it?

Comment: Welcome. Your question is very interesting if you add more details and elaborate more.

Answer (score 3):

Though I am completely at a loss about how such splitting could improve security in any sensible way, it is reasonably easy to distinguish the handshake from the rest of the traffic in a SSL connection. In SSL, everything is sent as *records*, with a regular format:

- content type (one byte)
- protocol version (two bytes)
- record length *L* (two bytes, big-endian)
- record payload (exactly *L* bytes)

To achieve what you want, you would look at the first header byte, which encodes the type of record: this value is equal to 20, 21, 22 or 23, with 23 meaning "application data" while the other values are for administrative processing (the handshake messages use type 22, and briefly 21 for the security parameter switching; alerts use type 20). All of this is specified in [section 6 of RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6).

With this knowledge, it is rather straightforward to implement a filter that sends records with type 23 one way, and records with other types another way. What can be difficult is interfacing with OS and applications; especially if you want to do that for existing applications that you cannot modify in any way. Also you will need both client and server to implement the splitting "over two separate networks".

I am not aware of any existing tool that does this job.

Comment: I think this may be possible with something like a load balancer using their scripting language to look for your criteria above however, like you alluded to, the two networks would have to be one hop out from either host or client, otherwise it will negotiate and then change networks, if this is one hop out though it should not detect different networks just as BGP may direct some packets over one route or another mid-conversation.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how this would improve security, unless your SSL traffic was being decrypted prior to arriving on your machine (proxy, load balancer etc).

If you really want to go outside of the box you could look at installing a software router on a machine that routs the traffic based on the filter Tom suggested. That would likely simplify the development of such a tool.